# Как добавлять элементы в список суммируя только с определенными индексами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Дан список:

```
A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Далее, выполняя определенные действия в цикле я получаю другие списки, как можно при каждом проходе по этому циклу обновлять элементы в главном писке `А`, например после первого прохода по циклу у нас был сформирован список B, вот с такими значениями:

```
for j in i:
    B = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

После этого список A обновится до `A = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, при втором проходе мы получили список с другими значениями `B = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]` и они должны суммироваться с уже имеющимися в `A`, то есть должно получится `A = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: `A = list(map(sum, zip(A, B)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный метод перебора индексов списка с помощью `range` и `len`:

```
for i in range(len(B)):
    A[i] += B[i]
```

Либо можно использовать `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(B):
    A[i] += x
```